# Solve for $x$. $8x-4 \sin(2x)=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me I can't seem to solve this equation. I tried isolating for theta but couldn't figure out how to because there was one in the sine function and one by itself. Please help. I'm studying for an exam tomorrow

Comment: Start with the hypothesis that $4\sin 2x = 0$  If that is not the case, you are going to have something ugly.

Comment: It's ugly I'm afraid.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried isolating for theta?"  I don't see a single theta in your problem.  Can you please provide some details about what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$8x-4\sin(2x)=\pi$$
Rearranging we get:
$$x=\frac\pi8+\frac12\sin(2x)$$

We can then approximate the solution using:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac\pi8+\frac12\sin(2x_n), x_0=1$$
To get the approximate solution of $x\approx0.8831701433$.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to know how you got the third equation ($xn+1=π8+12sin(2xn),x0=1$)

Comment: You see how the second equation is of the form $x=f(x)$? You can change these types of equations with transcendental solutions into iterations of the form $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, with a starting $x_0$ of your choice, then repeat the equation (usually by mashing $=$ on your calculator). The starter value $x_0=1$ is arbitrary, I picked it because I graphed the problem and found it reasonably close to the solution.